# Why ContentDocumentLink reference user?

Tags: contentdocumentlink

I need to add copy of Service Report when it is created in Service Appointment to its parent. To do so I tried to create trigger on ContentDocumentLink. My idea was to get this ContentDocumentLink, get its LinkedEntityId, find parent of this id and create new ContentDocumentLink. However in trigger LinkedEntityId reference to User that created this report. And after I query ContentDocumentLink by ContentDocument by hand I see that there is two ContentDocumentLinks, one for Service Appointment and one for User. How can I know to what object it was actually assigned in trigger?

Comment: Can u post ur code what u have tried so far

Comment: @AvijitDas There is not much to show. I only tried to see what was in debug and there is only ContentDocumentLink that reference User. I also noticed that ContentVersion tigger does not fire. So I can't think of any way that I can get id of object to what this report was added

Comment: what kind of report is this??? how it is linked to user???

Comment: as I understand, service report templates is some standard functionality in fsl package